# Difference between Wrapper and Native razor components

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I have some clarifications on blazor-server-side. what is the difference between blazor native and wrapper components? Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not using blazor, but following it a little bit since its first presentation, but I never heard of native and wrapper components [nor does the documentation include this wording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-components/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0). Therefore I might be wrong, but from the wording I get the idea, that by "wrapper" the interoperability is meant.

I am going to quote some text from [this excelent blog post](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/razor-components-for-a-javascript-free-frontend-in-2019)

Probably *native*, because the component is created only by .NET bl(r)azor without javascript:

> Since Razor Components runs server side as a .NET Standard app, logic is written using **.NET technologies**. This is possible due to the Blazor framework which employs the RenderTree, a DOM abstraction similar to virtual DOMs used in popular JavaScript frameworks like Angular and React. Let's look at UI side of the framework to understand how components are written.

```
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount">
  Click me
</button>

@functions {
  int currentCount = 0;

  [Parameter] protected int CountBy { get; set; } = 1;

  void IncrementCount()
  {
    currentCount += CountBy;
  }
}
```

Probably *wrapper*, because we use in our component the *interoperability layer* a JS Function.

> Additionally a Razor Components app can use dependencies the JavaScript ecosystems and through an interoperability layer the app can communicate bidirectionally with both **.NET and JavaScript dependencies**. This is helpful for situations where the Razor Components does not support a necessary browser/DOM API or an existing JavaScript library is useful.

*GeoLocation.cs (.NET)*

```
public class Geolocation
{
  // ...

  public async Task GetCurrentPosition(
    Action<Position> onSuccess,
    Action<PositionError> onError,
    PositionOptions options = null)
  {
    OnGetPosition = onSuccess;
    OnGetPositionError = onError;
    await JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<bool>(
      "interopGeolocation.getCurrentPosition",
      new DotNetObjectRef(this),
      options);
  }

  // ...
}
```

*interopGeolocation.js (Browser)*

```
window.interopGeolocation = {
  getCurrentPosition: function (geolocationRef, options) {
    const success = (result) => {
      geolocationRef.invokeMethodAsync(
        'RaiseOnGetPosition',
        interopGeolocation.toSerializeable(result));
    };
    const error = (er) =>
    geolocationRef.invokeMethodAsync(
      'RaiseOnGetPositionError',
      er.code);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      success,
      error,
      options);
},

// ...
```

Comment: Hi @christian, is there any advantages and disadvantages in performance difference in both types?

Comment: As I said, I am just following it at the moment, but do not work with it, especialy because its far from production ready. But from what I read, blazor does use WebAssembly (or loads a shim), then runs a custom mono build and then executing .net il. I expect wasm faster than javascript. Also we want use Blazor because we do not want to write Javascript. I think you should only use this if blazor doesn't support a feature or you do not want to rewrite an existing javascript component.